# How to build maven imported project in Intellij IDEA 11?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have created a new IntelliJ project by importing the maven projects. Which worked fine:
[image]

I can execute the maven goals from the Maven Projects pane (on the left side of the IDE screen). For instance, I can compile the projects just fine using the compile goal.

Now I want to build the project from the UI using the **Build|Make Project** option. However, it does not work. It complains about the missing application packages as if it does not see the dependencies. These dependencies are defined in the respective pom.xml files, but making the project from the IDE seems to ignore it.

What do I have to do to make it work?

**EDIT**

OK, I have deleted the **.m2** directory from my home and started the compile goal from the Maven Projects flyout. I can see in the console pane that maven downloads dependencies from the Maven Central (I am giving just first few lines of the log, it is quite long):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\java" -Dclassworlds.conf=O:\java\apache-maven-3.0.4\bin\m2.conf -Dmaven.home=O:\java\apache-maven-3.0.4 -Didea.launcher.port=7534 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "O:\java\apache-maven-3.0.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 11.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher --no-plugin-registry --fail-fast --strict-checksums --update-snapshots -f C:\dev\shunra\Application\Builder\build\vcat\pom.xml compile
[WARNING] Command line option -npr is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.shunra:VCat-build:pom:1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' uses an unsupported snapshot version format, should be '*-SNAPSHOT' instead. @ line 7, column 11
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] util.logging
[INFO] Infra
[INFO] dtos
[INFO] commons
[INFO] license
[INFO] core
[INFO] vcat
[INFO] VCat-build
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building util.logging 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom (7 KB at 7.2 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/19/maven-plugins-19.pom (11 KB at 38.7 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/19/maven-parent-19.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/19/maven-parent-19.pom (25 KB at 70.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/9/apache-9.pom (15 KB at 63.5 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar (26 KB at 63.1 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom (8 KB at 29.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/18/maven-plugins-18.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/18/maven-plugins-18.pom (13 KB at 53.6 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/16/maven-parent-16.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-parent/16/maven-parent-16.pom (23 KB at 66.8 KB/sec)
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom
Downloaded: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/7/apache-7.pom (15 KB at 59.5 KB/sec)
```

So, I suppose there is no problem connecting to the Maven Central.

**EDIT2**

Please, observe:
[image]
Notice the problem - there are two modules imported from Maven - **Common** and **Core**. Their Maven artifact Id are **commons** and **core** respectively. IntelliJ seems to confuse between the artifact Id and module name, because:

1. The Project flyout displays the module name followed by the respective maven artifact Id in parentheses.
2. In the Project settings dialog the modules are given by the respective maven artifact Id only.
3. But in the module dependencies it lists the module name only.

The **Core** module (maven artifact Id **core**) should see the dependency **Common** module (maven artifact Id **commons**), but it does not and this is the problem.

**EDIT3**

Here is the topmost pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
    <name>VCat-build</name>
    <version>1.0.0.SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>VCat-build</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>../../../util.logging</module>
        <module>../../../Infra</module>
        <module>../../../DTOs</module>
        <module>../../../ShunraLicense</module>
        <module>../../../Common</module>
        <module>../../../Core</module>
        <module>../../../VCat</module>
    </modules>
    <build>
        <plugins>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is the one for the Common module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.7</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
                <artifactId>util.logging</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.restlet.jse</groupId>
              <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
              <version>2.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
          <version>1</version>
          <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.3</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
            <artifactId>license</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
              <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
              <artifactId>dtos</artifactId>
              <version>0.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>maven-restlet</id>
       <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
       <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository> 
   </repositories>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

And here is the one for the Core module:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
  <artifactId>core</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.shunra</groupId>
        <artifactId>license</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source/>
          <target/>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**EDIT4**

Finally solved it. Removed all the Intellij files and reimported again. I guess the pom.xml files have changed in a way confusing to IntelliJ.

Comment: Have you checked to see that the perfect is a maven project? It doesn't sound like it has set its dependencies properly, e.g., it's not pulling them from the pom.

Comment: Just added **EDIT2** on the subject. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the screenshot, you don't appear to working offline which is the most common cause of this problem.

1. Try downloading sources and documentation from the Maven Projects flyout (it's the third icon in from the left). This often has the effect of waking it up and causing a download.
2. Perform a manual Maven build using the Runtime configuration. Select Edit Configurations | Maven then ensure your working directory is your project root, and select a goal of "clean package". This will force Intellij to rebuild directly through Maven which may wake up the internal background build process.
3. Check your settings and ensure that Intellj's Maven has correctly read the repository information from the POM and is able to locate Maven Central. You may have a problem with your local settings.xml that is preventing download.
4. You could also remove the .idea and .iml files to force a project re-import.
5. Restart Intellij and hope for the best...
6. As a last resort, invalidate your caches through File | Invalidate Caches. This might slow your development down a bit until they are rebuilt through use.

**Edit to cover updated question**

It appears that your POM files are in a bit of a mess. They don't follow the standard [Maven directory layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and as a result Intellij may be getting confused between your directory names and the internal artifactId entries. Often the parent POM (containing the modules) is placed in the root of the project, and modules form a directory hierarchy below.

With some extensive settings configuration you could coerce Intellij into working with the existing structure, but a better solution would be renaming the directories to match the artifactIds and moving the modules around so that they form a Maven reactor project.

**Further edit in light of comment**

Seems that it was the Intellij project synchronization. Deleting the .idea directory and .iml files did the trick. I've updated the list accordingly.

Comment: OK - has this fixed your problem since it appears to be downloading now?

Comment: Nope. Exactly the same result.

Comment: The thing is that IntelliJ does not seem to see the application module  dependencies. For instance, module A depends on module B, both A and B are our code, not third party. Maven compiles A fine, because pom.xml says A depends on B, but IntelliJ fails to compile the project with the modules A and B, because it cannot see B.

Comment: This sounds like a POM error. Does it work correctly from the command line? Can you post simplified versions of your POM files for examination?

Comment: It surely works from the command line. I will post the pom.xml files in a moment.

Comment: Added three pom.xml files. Sorry, I am not that familiar with maven in order to decide what is significant and what is not, so I just posted them complete.

Comment: I cannot place the sub modules under the root module, because there are several root modules sharing a largely overlapping set of sub modules. But I can try and rename the folder names to match artifact Ids.

Comment: +1 for all the effort, but in the end the problem is that IntelliJ does not seem to follow the changes in the pom.xml files. I have erased the .idea folder and all the .iml files and reimported. Now it works.

Comment: OK, no worries - I'll add the delete option to the solution in case anyone else has the same problem.